# SQL ORDER BY date ASC is omitting a record to be displayed

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to display a list of records with the following script:

```
$start=0;
$limit=20;

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$page_id=$_GET['page'];
$start=($page_id-1)*$limit;
}

$_SESSION['pageid'] = $page_id; /* to send to edit page */ 

$rows=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM subscribers");

$rows=mysqli_num_rows($rows);

if ($rows == 0) {$total = 1;}

else if ($rows > 0)
{$total=ceil($rows/$limit);}

?>

<table align="center" cellpadding="2" style="width:25%;">

<tr>
<td><b>Log Id</b></td>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><b>Expiry</b></td>
</tr>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT log_id, name, expiry FROM subscribers ORDER BY expiry ASC LIMIT $start, $limit";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$total_sub = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($total_sub > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["log_id"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["expiry"]; ?></td>
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['log_id'] ?>"><img src='img/edit.png' height='15'></a></td>

</tr>
<?php
  }  
  }  
?>

<tr><td align="center" colspan="4">
<?php
if($page_id > 1){
echo "<a href='?page=".($page_id-1)."'><img src='img/previous.png'></a>";
}

echo " ".$page_id."/".$total." ";

if($page_id!=$total){
echo "<a href='?page=".($page_id+1)."'><img src='img/next.png'></a>";
}

?>
</td></tr></table>
```

**Condition 1:**

- Page limit set to 20 records per page
- Display order by expiry date DESC
- User 1, 2 and 3 have the same dates (2020-11-28).

[image: Result of Condition 1]

- user1 and user2 (being 19th and 20th record) displayed on page 1
  while user3 is displayed on page 2.
- No issues.

**Condition 2:**

- Same as Condition 1 except that display order by expiry date is now
  set to ASC.

[image: Result of Condition 2]

- page 1 displays user1 (since it becomes the 20th record now due order
  change).
- page 2 displays user1 (again) and user3. Here comes the issue i.e.
  User2 is not displayed at all in this case.

**Condition 3:**

- Same as Condition 2 except that user1 now has a different date
  (2020-11-27) while user2 and 3 have same old dates (2020-11-28).

[image: Result of Condition 3]

- users 1,2,3 are displayed correctly even though the order is ASC. No
  issues.

**Condition 4:**

- Page limit set to 22 records per page (so that users 1,2,3 can be
  displayed on the same page).
- user 1, 2 and 3 have the same dates again (2020-11-28).
- Display order by expiry date is still ASC which seems to be causing
  the issue.

[image: Result of Condition 4]

- users 1,2,3 are displayed correctly even though order is ASC. No
  issues.

Cannot understand whats is causing the issue in condition 2 if ASC order is used? Thank you and sorry for the long question.

Comment: even tried a different browser but no help

Comment: do i need to edit the question to get a response, I added the detailed info for better visualization.